# C++ operator new, object versions, and the allocation sizes

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

I have a question about different versions of an object, their sizes, and allocation. The platform is Solaris 8 (and higher).

Let's say we have programs A, B, and C that all link to a shared library D. Some class is defined in the library D, let's call it 'classD', and assume the size is 100 bytes. Now, we want to add a few members to classD for the next version of program A, without affecting existing binaries B or C. The new size will be, say, 120 bytes. We want program A to use the new definition of classD (120 bytes), while programs B and C continue to use the old definition of classD (100 bytes). A, B, and C all use the operator "new" to create instances of D.

The question is, when does the operator "new" know the amount of memory to allocate? Compile time or run time? One thing I am afraid of is, programs B and C expect classD to be and alloate 100 bytes whereas the new shared library D requires 120 bytes for classD, and this inconsistency may cause memory corruption in programs B and C if I link them with the new library D. In other words, the area for extra 20 bytes that the new classD require may be allocated to some other variables by program B and C. Is this assumption correct?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't use new directly to allocate classD. Allocate classD through a function or interface that you control.

Comment: And if you allocate classD through a function, delete it through a function too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct the memory size is defined at compile time and applications B/C would be in danger of serious memory corruption problems.

There is no way to handle this explicitly at the language level. You need to work with the OS to get the appropriate shared libraries to the application.

You need to version your libraries.

As there is no explicit way of doing this with the build tools you need to do it with file names. If you look at most products this is approx how they work.

In the lib directory:

```
libD.1.00.so
libD.1.so     ->  libD.1.00.so    // Symbolic link
libD.so       ->  libD.1.so      // Symbolic link
```

Now at compile time you specify -lD and it links against libD.1.00.so because it follows the symbolic links. At run time it knows to use this version as this is the version it compiled against.

So you now update lib D to version 2.0

In the lib directory:

```
libD.1.00.so
libD.2.00.so
libD.1.so     ->  libD.1.00.so    // Symbolic link
libD.2.so     ->  libD.2.00.so    // Symbolic link
libD.so       ->  libD.2.so       // Symbolic link
```

Now when you build with -libD it links against version 2. Thus you re-build A and it will use version 2 of the lib from now on; while B and C will still use version 1. If you rebuild B or C it will use the new version of the library unless you explicitly use an old version of the library when building -libD.1

Some linkers do not know to follow symbolic links very well so there are linker commands that help. gcc use the '-install_name' flag your linker may have a slightly different named flag.

As a runtime check it is usally a good idea to put version information into your shared objects (global variable/function call etc). Thus at runtime you can retrieve the shared libraries version information and check that your application is compatible. If not you should exit with the appropriate error message.

Also note: If you serialize objects of D to a file. You know need to make sure that version information about D is maintained. Libd.2 may know how to read version 1 D objects (with some explicit work), but the inverse would not be true.

Comment: Thanks! We will take this approach.

Answer (score 6):

Changing the size of a class is *binary incompatible*. That means that if you change the size of `classD` without recompiling the code that uses it, you get undefined behavior (most likely crashes).

A common trick to get around this limitation is to design `classD` so that it can be safely extended in a binary compatible way, for example by using the [Pimpl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) idiom.

In any case, if you want different programs to use different versions of your class, I think you have no choice but releasing multiple versions of the shared library and have those programs linked to the appropriate version.

Answer (score 3):

Compile Time, you should not change shared object size underneath their clients.

there is a simple workaround for that:

```
class foo
{
public:
  // make sure this is not inlined
  static foo* Create()
  {
     return new foo();
  }
}

// at the client
foo* f = foo::Create();
```

Comment: This is called a class factory - quite useful, really

Comment: It is also not quite that simple. You must disable the ability for normal classes to be created (ie all obejcts must be dynamically created via Create()). You must also provide your own Destroy method that calls the destructor. You must gurantee that zero methods are inlined included default methods supplied by the compiler and thus you must provide your default implementations. To make this really usefull you need to wrap it in another class that dispatches the work to the dynamically created objects (ie you need to use the PIMPL patter as described by Paolo.

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocation is figured out at **compile time**. Changing the size of a class in D will trigger a recompile.

Consider publicly deriving from the class in question to extend it, if that would apply. Or, compose it in another object.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of memory to allocate is determined at compile time when doing something like

```
new Object();
```

but it can be a dynamic parameter such as in

```
new unsigned char[variable];
```

I really advise you to go through some middleware to achieve what you want. C++ guarantees nothing in terms of binary interfaces.

Have you looked at [protobuf](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/protocolbuffers/)?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the mentioned 'ad hoc' techniques, you can also model compatibility into your system by saying that your new class A is really a subclass of the 'old' class A.  That way, your old code keeps working, but all code that needs the extended functionality needs to be revised.

This design principle is clearly visible in the COM world, where especially interfaces are never changed over versions, only extended by inheritance.  Next to that, they only construct classes by the `CreateInstance` method, which moves the allocation problem to the library containing the class.